# Capture all errors in a powershell script and email

Tags: powershell

I have a script with many sections such as below that runs nightly. I would like to get it to email any/all errors so i can be alerted and review the errors. I'm having trouble with the first step which is to capture all/any errors... I assume to a file which i could email or capturing to some kind of buffer that i could then email would be even nicer. Any help with both steps would be appreciated - especially the capturing part.

```
#---- Set Exchange archive licnse for all users with an Office license ----
Get-MsolUser -ALL | where {($_.Licenses.accountskuID -contains 
"Tennant:STANDARDWOFFPACK") -and ($_.Licenses.accountskuID -notcontains 
"Tennant:EXCHANGEARCHIVE_ADDON")} | Set-MsolUserLicense -AddLicenses 
"Tennant:EXCHANGEARCHIVE_ADDON"


#-------------------------- ENABLE LITIGATION HOLD ----------------------
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {RecipientTypeDetails -eq 
"UserMailbox"} | Set-Mailbox -LitigationHoldEnabled $true -
LitigationHoldDuration 2555
```

Comment: Have you checked Start-Transcript for the capture part ?

Answer (score 0):

Error messages should automatically be captured in the `$error` variable; use `$error[0]` for the latest message.

You could then use that as the body for your email in conjunction with the `Send-MailMessage` Cmdlet

example:

```
$body = "";
foreach ($e in $error) {
    $body += "<hr /><pre>" + $e.ToString() + "</pre><hr />";
}
Send-MailMessage -BodyAsHtml -Body $body -SmtpServer "smtp_server_address" -From "alert@somedomain.tld" -To "your-email@somedomain.tld" -Subject "PowerShell Error Report"
```

Comment: Cool. Thank you.
The logging results show only part of the error like "licenses exceeded" but not other details like the command used "Set-MsolUserLicense". Is there a way to get more of the output so I have a better idea of which part of the scirpt may be failing?

Comment: The default $error output does show every possible thing that has gone wrong. The $error default output also only list a part of the error data. To get all the $error data, do this. $Error | Format-List -Force. Event still, you really need to enable script logging as noted above. Errors will be in several places, $Error, in the PoSH Transcript and in Windows Event logs - Application, Security and Windows PowerShell (which is a node under the Applications and Service logs).

Comment: The $error variable is just a collection of objects. My example only outputs a simple message as I used `.ToString()`. You can grab more detailed information from specific properties, or as @postanote noted, simply output all them in a list format

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you need to trap errors in order to log them, even write to your own event log...

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/02/01/use-powershell-to-create-and-to-use-a-new-event-log

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/06/20/how-to-use-powershell-to-write-to-event-logs

... or write your own log  function.

Example:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Write-Log-PowerShell-999c32d0

Or, start with using PowerShell logging.

Example:
Enable logging in Group Policy
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Write-Log-PowerShell-999c32d0

Use PowerShell transcript

Example:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff687007.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Then have those stored in a central share that you can pull into an email as an attachment.